# Reflection C# Get Custom Attributes from List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, reflection

I'd like to implement dynamic WebGrid Creation from Model.

The Idea is to Create a Grid from Model "Description" by annotating the Model Properties with attributes.

```
class Model
{
   public List<Product> Products {get;set;}

}

class Product 
{
   [GridColumn]
   public String Name {get;set;}
   ....

}
```

Then I'd like to Get By Reflection All properties marked by this Attribute.

```
public WebGridColumns[] ColumnsFromModel(object model)
{
   // Here model is List<T> so how get all custom attributes of List<T> ?


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a simple extension method that will get the attributes you want from an implementation of the [`ICustomAttributeProvider` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.icustomattributeprovider.aspx) (which is implemented by any representation of a .NET construct that can have an attribute on it):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetCustomAttributes(
    this ICustomAttributeProvider provider, bool inherit) where T : Attribute
{
    // Validate parameters.
    if (provider == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("provider");

    // Get custom attributes.
    return provider.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), inherit).
        Cast<T>();
}
```

From there, it's a call over all the `PropertyInfo` instances on a type, like so:

```
var attributes = 
    // Get all public properties, you might want to
    // call a more specific overload based on your needs.
    from p in obj.GetType().GetProperties()

    // Get the attribute.
    let attribute = p.GetCustomAttributes<GridColumnAttribute>().
        // Assuming allow multiple is false.
        SingleOrDefault().

    // Filter out null properties.
    where attribute != null

    // Map property with attribute.
    select new { Property = p, Attribute = attribute };
```

From there, you can call the [`GetType` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) on any object instance and run it through the above query to get the [`PropertyInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx) instance and the attribute that is applied to it.